# We could not deploy with a new process running

Tags: deployment, process-builder

I created a new process , When we tried to deploy change sets today, I received the unhandled process fault email message.

The message includes apex failure and Apex Failures:Pre deploy test failed, This may be because of custom validation rules in your Org. You can check ignore apex errors or temporarily deactivate your validation rules for Accounts and try again.

Encountered unhandled fault when running process

System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 --- for SFDC record with ID : null

Can some body please let me know how to deploy a process builder in active state and if we are getting the following error how to restrict them and the reason why they are coming. Are the relative trigger and test classes execute pre deployment

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean Process Builder process? Do you have any custom code in your production org? is it the same code in your sandbox / recent refreshed sandbox? Have you run all tests in your sandbox before deploying to make sure the process hasn't broken any code? Sounds to me that the process is impacting the something that is resulting in you hitting the SOQL governor limit.